# HttpWebRequest callback is blocked by UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

EDITED: On Windows Phone I am calling `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` on a separate thread that 
I started. Then I call MessageBox.Show(). The problem is that the callback is not called until I dismiss the MessageBox.

```
void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) {
    //Not getting called until I dismiss MessageBox
}

void getWeb() {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
}

new Thread(getWeb).Start(); //Start a new thread
MessageBox.Show();
```

Should the MessageBox be blocking the callback on the background thread?

Comment: little question: why do you create separate thread `new Thread(getWeb)` for method `getWeb()` that is already async by itself(`request.BeginGetResponse(...)` method does its job in the background)?

Comment: The idea is that I will have a loop on the background thread that continously sends off web requests with a pause of a couple of minutes between each request. Will it solve my problem if I call BeginGetResponse in the UI thread?

Comment: It might have to do with what comes *after* the call as well, Is it the method is never being called, or you hit the callback method and the code that marshals the call back to the UI isn't called?  It seems like you have some sort of deadlock going on.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the first line of the callback and it isn't called.

Comment: Instead of calling it from a background thread, I tried calling it on a Timer from the UI thread. It makes no difference. The callback is still not called until something is done on the UI:

Comment: My approach in similar situations usually is(if you haven't done it already): to try to localize problem as much as possible. I mean, remove all not related code(e.g. replace `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(..)` by your toy class that does `Thread.Sleep(..)`, then remove all the code from getWeb() method, etc), until problem is gone. When it's gone - then error is in the last removed thing.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Phone.Reactive`

Try this:

```
private void PushMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var scheduler = Scheduler.NewThread;
            scheduler.Schedule(action => GetWeb());         
            MessageBox.Show("This is a test.", "Test caption.", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }

        private void GetWeb()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

            httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(BeginGetResponseCallback, httpWebRequest);
        }

        private void BeginGetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

"MessageBox.Show();" will block your ui thread .

but i don't think it is the reason the GetResponseCallback does not run.

you can test it , comment  that code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `MessageBox.Show();`

then place a this inside dispacher

```
void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult) 
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    });

}

void getWeb() {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
}

new Thread(getWeb).Start(); //Start a new thread
```